# Interval keeps instantly refreshing when I want the first one to timeout first

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So, I am using a battle system that uses intervals and I am having issues trying to keep it from spamming when I initiate the function. It doesn't create multiple intervals it'll just keep refreshing, and if i stop pressing the button it is tied to, it'll go about as normal. I am not sure where I am messing up at, it all looks right to me.

```
Updated code below
```

Okay so I have updated my code where it won't keep spamming the fight function. However I am now having an issue where it creates multiple `setTimeeout()` functions:

```
// FIGHT CALL
  socket.on('fight mob', (mobId) => {
    //socket.emit('mob test', data);
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM mobs WHERE id = ?';

    // If there is no interval, or if it is false, intiate one.
    if (session.userdata.actionInterval === undefined) {
      db.query(sql, mobId).then(results => {
        session.userdata.actionInterval = setInterval(() => {
          battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
          session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
        }, 6000);

        session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
        session.userdata.autos = 5;
        battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
      });
    } else { // If there is a current interval... do this
      var timing = session.userdata.intervalTime + 5900 - Date.now();
      if (timing < 0) timing = 0;
      console.log(timing);

      // Waits for current to end, then updates it.
      db.query(sql, mobId).then(results => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          clearInterval(session.userdata.actionInterval);
          session.userdata.actionInterval = setInterval(() => {
            battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
            session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
          }, 6000);

          session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
          session.userdata.autos = 5;
          battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
        }, timing);
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found an answer, I doubt it is the most elegant and/or efficient but it is currently doing the trick. I had issues with it clearing the interval but I also fixed that... took too long IMO but ya live and you learn.

```
  // FIGHT CALL
  socket.on('fight mob', (mobId) => {

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM mobs WHERE id = ?';

    // If there is no interval, or if it is false, intiate one.
    if (session.userdata.actionInterval === undefined || session.userdata.actionInterval === false) {
      db.query(sql, mobId).then(results => {
        session.userdata.actionInterval = setInterval(() => {
          battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
          session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
        }, 6000);
        session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
        session.userdata.autos = 5;
        battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
      });
    } else { // If there is a current interval... do this
      var timing = session.userdata.intervalTime + 5900 - Date.now();
      if (timing < 0) timing = 0;

      // Waits for current to end, then updates it.
      db.query(sql, mobId).then(results => {
        if (session.userdata.actionTimeout === undefined) {
          session.userdata.actionTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            session.userdata.actionInterval = clearInterval(session.userdata.actionInterval);
            session.userdata.actionInterval = setInterval(() => {
              battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
              session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
            }, 6000);

            session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
            session.userdata.autos = 5;
            battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
          }, timing);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```